# Youtube video as page background

Tags: ecommerce, cdn, youtube, background-image

I'm creating a page for the customer, and I wanted to use youtube video as a page background.
I don't know if it's legit (or prohibited) to use youtube like CDN server (cuz it uses their bandwidth outside their service) on commercial site (shop). Can someone explain this or someone else had this problem before?

The videos that will be used as background is owned by my customer and will be uploaded to their youtube channel.

Edit:
I want to ask if youtube licence or any other document prevents to use it like CDN server on page where movie will be used as background (no control, youtube logo displays only for few seconds). This page is a shop so it's commercial use. Page have ~1600 visits per week.

Comment: Not a problem (unless you're huge). There are a lot of example scripts for this, I suggest you check them out.

Comment: Maybe opinion has changed, but constantly moving images (such as in a banner) always used to be considered bad for accessibility?

Comment: IMO background movies can be quite awesome, if used properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [YouTube terms of service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms):

> If you use the Embeddable Player on your website, you may not modify, build upon, or block any portion or functionality of the Embeddable Player, including but not limited to links back to the YouTube website.

Using their embedded player as a page background would appear to violate the terms of service because:

- It builds upon the service
- Items in front of it would block functionality

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:**

This is totally fine. Google hosts tons of libraries (the most popular library probably being [jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)) and content on their CDN which is available for public use.

**Part 2:**

If I understood what your *edit* meant, you're wanting to know if you can use a YouTube video as a background even if it doesn't show any YouTube logos or controls?

Is that is what you're asking, the answer is also yes. That is totally fine to do. Which is why Google has made it an [option that is available in their YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding).

Answer (score 1):

This HTML snippet should do the trick ([demo](http://img.labnol.org/files/video-background.html))

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
    src="https://youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

See tutorial: [YouTube Video as Background](http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-video-background/27933/)

Comment: Note that the OP edited the question after this answer to be specific to whether the YouTube license prevents this or not.